# MS Access Binding Textfield to tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am currently building a MS Access database as a project @Work.
The Database is fed with a huge, not sorted Table `DataQueryExport`, and the objective is to create a GUI that makes that huge table workable.

Now to the question:
I have a textfield `Comment` that is supposed to show a comment to a specific data entry `WorkID`. The `WorkID` Is stored in a seperate table called `WorkID_Comments` which is filled via SQL query. The Table `WorkID_Comments`has 2 columns, `WorkID`and `Comment`.

The GUI has a ComboBox `WorkID_Combo`, where you can select a specific WorkID from the main Table `DataQueryExport`. This exact value is what is supposed to be used as a reference to show the comment for that WorkID.

TL:DR; I need the Comment Box to show and store the Text I wrote for that Value selected in the ComboBox. How do I get the Textfield to show the Value from the Table `WorkID_Comments.Comments` where the Value in `WorkID_Combo`(View ComboBox) is the same as `WorkID_Comments.WorkID`

I apologize beforehand for any weird capitalizations, I am used to it, German is my main language.

Thank you for reading, I am thankful for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a query in the query designer with your needed columns (If I understood it correctly: ID and the Comment).
Then go to your combobox and chose under properties recordsource `table/query` and your designed query.

Now you can specify which colums should be shown and use the ID as the value in the background.

Then bind another query to your form (here is the text you wrote as column) which is linked to the ID from the combox. Put a textbox in the form and use the column as source.

Comment: The Colum `WorkID_Comment` is supposed to be shown in a text box. the ComboCox is the Value that the entry in the text box is refering to.

I wrote the Query, but the TextBox has no "recordsource".

Thank you for the fast response

Comment: At the textbox properties look under `Data` and `Control Source`. If your form is bound to a query you can chose a column from that query

Comment: That sounds plausible, however, i have not bound the query to the form. How do I do that?

Comment: Click in design mode on the left corner of your form (black rectangle), this way you get the form propertys there you will find the `Data` tab and then the `Record source` property.